# Pyad connection to another server

Tags: python, active-directory, pyad

Can someone help me to solve my issue?
I try to download some user-info from server's active directory.
When I tried that without pyad_setdefaults - that's ok.
But when I try to connect to another server -I have an error.

```
import pyad
import pyad.adquery
pyad.pyad_setdefaults(ldap_server= 'myserv', username= 'login', password= 'pass'
q = pyad.adquery.ADQuery()
attributes = ['SamAccountName']
q.execut_equery(attributes= attributes)
result= q.get_all_results()
```

And i have this error:
[image]

I tried pyad.pyad.set_defaults - there were the same error.
My server has a connection to another.
And this account has an acces to AD.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out.
If you want to use adquery , you need to set default server:

```
import pyad
import pyad.adquery
q = pyad.adquery.ADQuery()
attributes = ['SamAccountName']
q.default_ldap_server = server_address
q.default_username = user_login
q.default_password = user_password
q.execute_query(attributes= attributes)
result= q.get_all_results()
```

Sometimes you need to indicate base_dn in execute_query.